# Why CocoaPod copy all framework to final iOS app product?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I code my app by Swift and use some Pods. I open the AppName.app (Show Package Content), and found that Frameworks folder size is too big. Beside the Swift libs (it's usual), CocoaPod copy all frameworks to that folder.

I didn't see that problem when I used CocoaPod with Objective C in the past. But now when I move to Swift, CocoaPod copy all of Pods to this folder, make the final product is too big.

Is it something wrong in my CocoaPod settings?

Comment: For ObjC CocoaPod copies libraries, not frameworks.

Comment: Where is the libraries copied. I think it build cocoapod code to app binary file

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. How else would your app be able to use the frameworks? Are you sure it didn't do this with Objective-C?

Comment: In my old app, I don't see it copy framework to that folder. I think it build cocoapod code to app binary file, not to separated framework file